# Did EgyptAir publish this totally messed up map from Europe?

Tags: advertising

Today I've come across this image:

[image]

While the site itself only claims that Helsinki has been moved to Siberia, you will quickly notice that most countries and even the seas are severely displaced.

Googling for "Egypt Air European Map" or "Egypt Air wrong map" did not yield any results. Did the airline really mess  up this bad?

Comment: Milan should be labelled Padua or Venice in that map... Milan is in the north west, not north east of Italy.

Comment: *Where* did you come across this?

Comment: The Facebook site VeryFinnishProblems

Comment: It's not obvious in the picture from VeryFinnishProblems, but this isn't a screenshot, it's a photo of a book. What book I can't say, but a different photo of the page was [posted on Reddit 4 years ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/CrappyDesign/comments/2xns7c/egyptairs_route_map/), so someone may get an answer by asking the user there.

Comment: On this map, Vienna and Sofia are in Eastern Ukraine next to Kiev; and Prague is where Minsk actually is.

Comment: I think it's pointless to point out (ha!) all the flaws in this picture, as this would be a quite long list.

Comment: If anyone has Adobe Flash Player installed, you can look at [their inflight magazine from 2014](https://www.egyptair.com/en/fly/Pages/Magazines.aspx) (before the 2015 Reddit post - might be too long before, there don't seem to be any from 2015 online). Also here's another, different photo of the same map from someone on Twitter who implies they independently noticed and photographed this a few years ago - https://twitter.com/fffisch/status/1093782205409738752. Looks likely to be real

Comment: And as for "Did the airline really mess up this bad?" - this isn't the only example of EgyptAir's inflight magazine's less-than-sky-high editorial standards, see for example its [notorious "interview" with Drew Barrymore](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2018/oct/04/drew-barrymore-did-not-participate-in-bizarre-egyptair-interview-representatives-claim)

Comment: Then again, New Zealand is completely left out on quite notable maps ...

Comment: Looks like a map generated by a bugged program. So many errors that it suggests some negligence by the editor, but it does not seem something so exceptional to make the news.

Answer (score 8):

There is an identical [imgur](https://imgur.com/gallery/btpocs0/comment/359314944) picture from 2015 that purports to be a screenshot from a 2015 issue of the inflight magazine, including a link to said magazine. The linked page contains an [embedded Flash file](https://www.egyptair.com/NewPages/Magazine/Jan2015/files/3dissue.swf) with the content of the magazine.

Displaying the Flash file in standalone Flash Player reveals that EgyptAir indeed published the map:

[image: Messed-up map as published by EgyptAir]

The map must have been corrected during the year 2015, as this [Flight report](https://flight-report.com/en/report/12964/Egyptair-MS996-Toronto-YYZ-Cairo-CAI/) from December 2015 already shows a [version](https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1443/24448970701_5f8d5788b4_b.jpg) that seems correct. It might have to do with a [change in publisher](http://ppp-org.com/Partner/Index/en/14/Horus) (May 2013-September 2015 was 'PP&P')